# Why is compile called, but link isn't?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a UI using AngularJS and transitioning from jQuery.
The UI itself is a wizard, and one of the steps has sub-steps that should be activated by the press of a button. Here is the solution I currently have.

AngularJS code

```
.controller('StepCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.substeps = [];
    $scope.activeStep = '';
    $scope.isActive = function(stepName) {
        // this is never called
        return activeStep == stepName;
    }
    $scope.changeActiveStep = function(newStepName) {
        $scope.activeStep = newStepName;
    };
})

.directive('subStep', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // this is never called
            var name = $attrs.name;
            $scope.substeps.push(name);
        },
        compile: function($element, $attrs) {
            var stepName = $attrs.name;
            $element.attr('ng-show', 'isActive(\''+stepName+'\')');
        }
    }
})

.directive('activateSubStep', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var enabledStep = $attrs.activateSubStep;
            $element.on('click', function() {
                $scope.changeActiveStep(enabledStep);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

JADE layout

```
.step(ng-controller='StepCtrl')
    p Pick an option
    button.btn-default(activate-sub-step='sub-step-1') Sub-Step 1
    button.btn-default(activate-sub-step='sub-step-2') Sub-Step 2 

    .sub-step(sub-step name='sub-step-1')
            ....
    .sub-step(sub-step name='sub-step-2')
            ....
```

The idea is that by clicking the Sub Step 1 button, I will display the view of `.sub-step(sub-step name='sub-step-1')`. However my issue currently is that `link` on the `subStep` directive is not being called, which means that substeps aren't being registered in the controller, and that `isActive()` is also not being called by the substep `ng-show` attribute.

The buttons are working correctly. I was under the impression that `transclude`-ing the substep would allow for them to 'see' the `StepCtrl` scope and thus be able to invoke `isActive` and/or push to `substeps`, but it appears this it not the case.

Oddly enough, `compile` on `subStep` *is* being called and *is* working correctly. There are no compiler errors and `link` on `subStep` is not being invoked at all whatsoever.

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, `compile` has to return `link`. There's something I wasn't expecting.